# Defined PHP class from another file not working

Tags: php, class, defined

I am currently learning PHP, but I have run into a problem.

I have a class that allows you to create an event and set/get its name, date, description and price. It is currently in a file called "class_lib.php".

```
<?php 
class Eventitem
{
    private $eventName;
    private $eventDate;
    private $eventDesc;
    private $eventPrice;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventName = "BLANK";
        $this->eventDate = "January 1";
        $this->eventDesc = "...";
        $this->eventPrice = "$0.00";
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->eventName = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->eventName;
    }       

    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->eventDate;
    }

    public function getDesc()
    {
        return $this->eventDesc;
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->eventPrice;
    }
}
?>
```

Now, in another file that I'm using as a testbed, called "blank.php", I tried to define the class and use its setName and getName methods:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">
        <?php include 'class_lib.php'; ?>
        <?php
            $event = new Eventitem();
            $event->setName("Some Event");

            echo $event->getName();

        ?>
    </div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>
```

However, when I execute it, nothing shows up! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `ìnclude` to `require`. Does your script fall over?

Comment: Still blank. What do you mean by fall over?

Comment: This class does not compile. Instance properties used to be declared using `var` in PHP 4 but since PHP 5 they must be declared using [`public`, `protected` or `private`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Remove `var`. Also, it is recommended to declare the visibility of all methods (including the constructor). It is not required and not needed in your code as the default visibility is `public` but it's better to be consistent and declare the visibility of all methods.

Comment: Done. Are there any other issues? I tried out the revised code, but it still came up a blank page.

Comment: [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is a language construct, not a function. It is not needed to put parenthesis around its argument. Even more, there are situations when the parentheses mislead the reader. They do not break your script though.

Comment: I forgot about those parentheses and fixed them immediately. Still a blank slate - could it be something wrong about how I call the methods within the class?

Comment: Can you try enabling errors: ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the page and post what are the errors displayed?

Comment: @SomnathSinha Just a misspelling error on one of my function calls. Rectified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied and pasted your code onto my localhost and it works fine.

[image]

What you have here is an issue running php scripts via whatever web server you're trying to use. Make sure you can get any php script running, such as `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: I ran other scripts using my web server (EasyPHP Webserver) including phpinfo(), and they display just fine. It's just _**this**_ script that's having problems.

Comment: UPDATE: Fixed it. Just a minor typo.